# tilde and hat together over a letter

Tags: symbols

Hey guys I have a problem. I need to write some letters with both tilde and bar or tilde and hat at the same time but I cannot find any functions that allow so. Do you know any?

Comment: Is it in text or in math?

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}

$\hat{\tilde{a}}$


$\tilde{\hat{a}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to mention explicitly that it's not actually necessary to load the `amsmath` package in order to combine `\hat` and `\tilde` accents.